# Query regarding SPOJ TEST

Tags: c++

I might be wrong in asking an SPOJ problem on this forum but I wanted to understand one mechanism which I wanted to know from the enriched community here.

Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.

Example

Input:
1
2
88
42
99

Output:
1
2
88

## My Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n,i=0;
   int a[100] = {0};
   while((cin>>n))
   {
      a[i] = n;
      i++;
      continue;
   }

   for(int j = 0;a[j]!=42;j++)
      cout<<a[j]<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

## Good Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n;
   while(true)
   {
      cin>>n;
      if(n == 42)
         break;
      cout<<n<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

My query is what happens to the input in the good solution?We would be running the loop only till the number is not 42.How does Good solution handle the remaining input?I got some hint that it is somewhat related to buffering and all.Please provide me some explanation or links or study material or at least some keyword to google etc to get clarity on this.

Comment: Bad solution has undefined behavior with 101+ input numbers.

Comment: Good solution discards remaining input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remaining input in good solution will be ignored by "good solution".

If you need more info read:

object

**[std::cin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/)**

extern istream cin;

Standard input stream 
Object of class istream that represents the standard input stream oriented to narrow characters (of type char). It corresponds to the C stream stdin.

The standard input stream is a source of characters determined by the environment. It is generally assumed to be input from an external source, such as the keyboard or a file.

object

**[stdin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/)**
FILE * stdin;

Standard input stream
The standard input stream is the default source of data for applications. In most systems, it is usually directed by default to the keyboard.

stdin can be used as an argument for any function that expects an input stream (FILE*) as one of its parameters, like fgets or fscanf.